# Finding largest circle which entirely included in multipolygon and not containing any point of points layer

Tags: algorithm

I have two layers*:

- 1 MultiPolygon (the complex green features)
- 1 MultiPoint (many thousands of yellow dots)

[image: data]

How can I **efficiently** find the largest circle (center coordinates + radius) which is **both**
a) entirely included in the MultiPolygon *and*
b) which doesn't contain any point of the MultiPoint layer?

The points are already filtered and they are absolutely all within the MultiPolygon.

E.g. these could be these two circles here:
[image: result example]

For the moment I don't have any implementation. I'm more thinking of the general way to get to the goal because I didn't find a tool ready for that particular task.

Comment: If you are not wanting help with code then consider replacing your Python tag with one for algorithm instead, and remove references to the software you are using to constrain your solution.

Comment: It looks like your points are already guaranteed to be within your polygons but if that is the case then I think that should be stated within your question.

Comment: I think you may need to look at the [math.se] Stack Exchange where [Largest enclosed (inscribed) circle in cloud of points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835931/largest-enclosed-inscribed-circle-in-cloud-of-points) seems somewhat similar to where you are stuck.

Comment: Extract the vertices of the polygon and merge them with your initial points. Run overlay_nearest with QIGS expressions to find those points that have the biggest distance between them. This could be a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I can offer up a solution.

1. Extract the vertices of you boundary into a separate dataset
2. Merge these points with your points in the polygon
3. Run the Euclidean distance tool with an appropriate cell size on the merged points and mask by the boundary, you get this:

[image: Distance]

4. Convert the raster cells to points
5. Use the boundary to select the points
6. Sort the selection and take the largest distance
7. Buffer that point by that distance and you get:

[image: Circle]

So there is your circle that fulfils your requirements the largest circle possible for the points that is *also* constrained by the boundary.

You could easily automate this in model builder or as a python script.

Comment: +1, I think have seen a similar answer from you, like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390958/buffering-with-obstacles

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how many points and polygons you have, but this executes in 1.3 sec for 500 points within one polygon.

It is based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835931/largest-enclosed-inscribed-circle-in-cloud-of-points), that "The center of the largest inscribed circle will be on one of the (linearly many) Voronoi nodes.".

I buffer the nodes with the distance to the closest other point, then select the buffer with the largest area that are within the input polygon and doesnt overlap any input points.

[image]

[image]

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : model
Group : 
With QGIS : 32202
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('polygonboundlayer', 'polygon bound layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('points', 'points', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Largest_circle', 'largest_circle', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Extracted', 'extracted', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(13, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Voronoi polygons
        alg_params = {
            'BUFFER': 200,
            'INPUT': parameters['points'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['VoronoiPolygons'] = processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract vertices
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['VoronoiPolygons']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractVertices'] = processing.run('native:extractvertices', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Clip
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractVertices']['OUTPUT'],
            'OVERLAY': parameters['polygonboundlayer'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Clip'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Clip
        # The voronoi extend outside layer bounds
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['VoronoiPolygons']['OUTPUT'],
            'OVERLAY': parameters['polygonboundlayer'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Clip'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Delete duplicate geometries
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['Clip']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['DeleteDuplicateGeometries'] = processing.run('native:deleteduplicategeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Multipart to singleparts
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['DeleteDuplicateGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['MultipartToSingleparts'] = processing.run('native:multiparttosingleparts', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator
        # Add a id field "newid" as @row_number
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'newid',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Integer
            'FORMULA': '@row_number',
            'INPUT': outputs['MultipartToSingleparts']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Distance matrix
        # Find closest input point from each voronoi point
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_FIELD': 'newid',
            'MATRIX_TYPE': 0,  # Linear (N*k x 3) distance matrix
            'NEAREST_POINTS': 1,
            'TARGET': parameters['points'],
            'TARGET_FIELD': 'id',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['DistanceMatrix'] = processing.run('qgis:distancematrix', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Multipart to singleparts
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['DistanceMatrix']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['MultipartToSingleparts'] = processing.run('native:multiparttosingleparts', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Variable distance buffer
        # Buffer by the Distance field created in Distance matrix
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'FIELD': 'Distance',
            'INPUT': outputs['MultipartToSingleparts']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['VariableDistanceBuffer'] = processing.run('qgis:variabledistancebuffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by location
        # Extract the buffers that are within input polygons
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['VariableDistanceBuffer']['OUTPUT'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['polygonboundlayer'],
            'PREDICATE': [6],  # are within
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByLocation'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by location
        # Extract buffer that doesnt overlap input points
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByLocation']['OUTPUT'],
            'INTERSECT': parameters['points'],
            'PREDICATE': [2],  # disjoint
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Extracted']
        }
        outputs['ExtractByLocation'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Extracted'] = outputs['ExtractByLocation']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(12)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by expression
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'area($geometry) = maximum(area($geometry))',
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByLocation']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Largest_circle']
        }
        outputs['ExtractByExpression'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Largest_circle'] = outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Model()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution: the idea

The principle: Create a new polygon with holes by "cutting out" the points (buffer them with a small distance), then find the pole of inaccessability and draw a circle around it with the distance to the nearest point on the boundary of the polygon.

### Step by step implementation

1. Create a small buffer around the points.
2. Use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing / Difference`, set the polygon as input and the buffer as overlay layer.

   Like this, you have a polygon with many holes (a swiss cheese...). This reduces the problem to find the largest circle inside the polygon - we don't have to keep in mind the points.
3. Find the Pole of inaccessability: `pole_of_inaccessibility ($geometry, 1)`. **Be aware**: see below to set an appropriate tolerance value here instead of `1`.
4. Find the closest point to the Point from step 3 on the boundary of the polygon:

   ```
   closest_point( 
      boundary($geometry),
      pole_of_inaccessibility ($geometry, 1)
   )
   ```
5. The line connecting the point from step 3 to the one from step 4 is the radius of the circle, the point from step 3 the center. Thus you can get the circle combining both. Set below for tolerance value (here: `0.2`):

   ```
    with_variable (
        'pole',
        pole_of_inaccessibility ($geometry, 0.2),
        make_circle (
            @pole,
            length (
                make_line (
                    @pole,
                    closest_point( 
                        boundary($geometry),
                        @pole
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
   ```

[image]

### Importance of tolerance settings

`pole_of_inaccessibility` uses an iterative approach to approximate the real Pole of inaccessability. So setting an appropriate value for `tolerance` (`0.2` on line 3 in the expression above) is key to a good result. The smaller the value is, the better the result gets - but it also takes longer to calculate. Tolerance should be smaller then the radius of the circle: based on your data, try to speculate the length of the radius, try from there and then reduce the value further

The following images show how a good tolerance value is crucial for this solution: the smaller it is, the better the result is. From tolerance 1 down to 0.5, the area where the circle appears jumps around the whole polygon. From 0.3 down the place of the circle remains more or less in the same area, but the smaller the tolerance gets, the larger the circle gets:

*Tolerance = 1*
[image]

*Tolerance = 0.7*
[image]

*Tolerance = 0.5*
[image]

*Tolerance = 0.3: finally, the circle is more or less in the correct place, but still does not have the maximum radius (compare to the solution above):*
[image]