# Visualizing proximity to nearest park in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity

I'm relatively new to QGIS but have undertaken a project trying to understand access to parks in a neighborhood of nyc. I want to visualize the proximity to the nearest park from the entrance of each building (since it's nyc, I'm imagining walking distance from the front door to the nearest park entrance). I do not want to create buffer zones since I am already looking at a small area - I need more precise measurements.

I have point data for each park entrance, as well as street centerlines and building footprints for the area of interest, but am conceptually stuck on how to combine this information in QGIS.

I'm ideally looking to measure the distance from each potential building in the area which is far too many to enter individually for the batch process. I was able to create interpolated points along the centerline.. would that help me measure distance from each of those points to the nearest park entrance?

Comment: What research on routing have you done?

Comment: This related question may give you some idea : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390958/buffering-with-obstacles/390967#390967

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest path (point to layer)

Under `Toolbox` search `Shortest path (point to layer)`.

you will be presented with a window like this:

[image]

where you can select:

- the network layer (your centrelines)
- the endpoint (park entrances)

alas, a user interaction is required to pick the the starting point (building), but one can batch the process clicking on the `Run as Batch Process`, where the start point(s) can be entered one per row.

Comment: I'm ideally looking to measure the distance from each potential building in the area which is far too many to enter individually for the batch process. I was able to create interpolated points along the centerline.. would that help me measure distance from each of those points to the nearest park entrance?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I had to know the closest distance from points to the nearest node of a polygon (id = 1 here)

> distance( closest_point( segments_to_lines( geometry(
> get_feature_by_id('polygons', 1 ))),$geometry)
> ,$geometry)

[image]

Comment: This can be done with the `join by nearest` tool, too. Also, it doesn't answer the question asked.